# invalid or unknown key object_lock_configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, locking

Trying to set Object Locking on an AWS bucket module (which is working fine without object locking configuration) I get the error :

> invalid or unknown key: object_lock_configuration

The error message makes me think about a syntax error but can't see it, so here is the bucket definition:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "new_b" {
  bucket = "${lower(var.sia)}-${var.bucket_name}-${lower(var.env)}"
  acl    = "${var.bucket_acl}"

  object_lock_configuration {
    object_lock_enabled = "${var.locking}"
  }
  lifecycle_rule {
    id      = "default"
    prefix  = ""
    enabled = "${var.default_lifecycle}"
    expiration {
      days = "${var.default_expiry_days}"
    }
  }
  tags {
    Name = "${lower(var.sia)}-${var.bucket_name}-${lower(var.env)}"
    Sia = "${upper(var.sia)}"
    Env = "${upper(var.env)}"
    Author = "${var.author}"
  }
}
```

I am running it with : 
Terraform v0.11.13
+ provider.aws v1.52.0
+ provider.template v1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Setting object lock configuration for a bucket requires version 1.56.0 of the Terraform AWS provider.

cf. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6634#issuecomment-454621706